# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.document.createElement')

Tags: react-native, flipper

I want to use flipper for performance debugging through DevTools , as soon as i open flipper and connect it with my react native app i am getting below error.

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> 'window.document.createElement')

If i keep flipper closed , not getting such error . Please help me out.

Comment: have checked with add ternary condition.?

Comment: @MeetMajevadiya yes

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why this is happening but found a workaround by doing some quick issue search on [react-native repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35958#issuecomment-1411242775).

In Flipper -> React DevTools press the settings icon on the top right and under General there is a pre-ticked checkbox called **Highlight updates when component re-renders**.

When you disable this the error goes away!

enter image description here[image]

Comment: Same issue, same solution! Thanks!